# Bash script exercise in Windows environment

Tags: linux, shell-script, windows

I have this exercise

> Write a script which
>
> - creates files   `File.txt`  `numer.txt`
>
>   - the first contains the list of script arguments, separated by newline,
>   - the second contains your UID,   if at least one of then already exists display an error message and exit;
> - creates subdirectory `C:\WINDOWS` in your home and copies to it the above two files;
> - sets the file permissions to files in `C:\WINDOWS` in such a way that only the user owner and group owner can modify the files, others can
>     only read;
> - creates a symbolic link to `/bin` in `C:\WINDOWS`;
> - creates `SYSTEM32` file in `C:\WINDOWS` containing the list of all the files from your home;

and this code

```
#!/bin/bash

touch File.txt
touch numer.txt
for i in $@
do 
    echo $i >> File.txt
done
id -u >> numer.txt
if $(test -e numer.txt)
then 
    echo Error message
    exit
fi
mkdir C:\WINDOWS
cp File.txt C:\WINDOWS
cp numer.txt C:\WINDOWS
ln -s C:\WINDOWS bin/link
ls $HOME > SYSTEM32
```

Anybody can help with this? I don't know if I solved it correctly and when I run it it always prints 'Error Message'.

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* that that's what it's asking you to do all at once, and in a Bash script?

Comment: Yes, im sure for that. My teacher asked me abouth that.

Comment: Are you running this on a Windows machine with `bash`? If so, I'd expect it to be difficult to create a directory called `C:\WINDOWS` under your home directory...  In any case, you probably want to tell us what the error message is that you say you get.

Comment: I'm running it on PUTTY, Maybe i have understand it not correctly. If you have any idea please help me :)

Comment: The `numer.txt` exist that's why it's printing  Error message (assuming you're running it on Git Bash or any cygwin related applications on windows)

Comment: You would have to test for the existence of the files _first_ (with `if [ -e numer.txt ] || [ -e File.txt ]`), then possibly write to them. If you write to them first, of course they would exist.

Comment: Please can you edit my code if you undestood that?

Comment: are you asking @Kusalananda to do your schoolwork for you?

Comment: @Edward Regarding your change of title: How do you know that this is running in a Windows environment?

Comment: @Kusalananda an educated guess giving the filenames, but I concur that's not 100% waterproof. AniHoxha do you want to shed some light on this?

Comment: i got the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's quite a few mistakes so please excuse me doing this for you.  I've commented the changes:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# check if files exist and exit 
if [ -f File.txt -o -f numer.txt ] ; then
    echo "Files exist" >&2
    exit 1
fi
## You need this incase there are no arguments
touch File.txt
# but you don't need this
# touch numer.txt

# Always use "$@" not $@, use "$i" not $i
for i in "$@"
do 
    echo "$i" >> File.txt
done
## Really this should be > not >> (you are not appending to an existing)
id -u > numer.txt
# If you test for the file existing after you create it, it will always exist!
#if $(test -e numer.txt)
#then 
#    echo Error message
#    exit
#fi
# \ is the control character to write a single \ use \\
mkdir C:\\WINDOWS
cp File.txt C:\\WINDOWS
cp numer.txt C:\\WINDOWS
# The link should be in C:\WINDOWS and point to bin
ln -s bin C:\\WINDOWS
# one file per line (-1).  And generally use ~ for your home
ls -1 ~ > C:\\WINDOWS/SYSTEM32
```

Comment: or `printf '%s\n' "$@" >File.txt` instead of that loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. Working Perfectly.

Comment: @AniHoxha Good! If this solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: In bash (and plenty of other more "windows native" places) you can use forward slashes for file names when they can't be mistaken for something else.

Comment: @xenoid In context I believe the OP actually wanted a directory named `C:\WINDOWS` not a directory called `C:` containing another directory named `WINDOWS`.  The obscure clue is in the colon (:).  No Linux emulators (cygwin etc) that I know of retain the colon and the quote says to create this directory, not simply write into it.